# How do you get JFrame from main to make fullscreen?

Tags: java, window, jframe, fullscreen

I have my JFrame defined in main and I want to make it so if I click a button, press F, etc., the screen goes full screen. I understand how to do this, but I do not understand how to get the JFrame instance out of main for the setFullScreenWindow, like how you might get the player's x by using a getter.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
private boolean fullscreen = false;

public static void main(String args[]){
    Game game = new Game();

    //Set size of game (not shown)

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(game.TITLE);
    frame.add(game);
    //JFrame setup stuff (not shown)

    game.start();
}

public void setFullScreen(JFrame frame){
    if(isFullScreenSupported){
        if(!fullscreen){
            frame.setUndecorate(true);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            frame.validate;
        } else{
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
     }
}
```

I cannot add a parameter to start(), btw. There are a bunch of complicated and necessary steps in between.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you're looking to toggle your JFrame between windowed and full-screen modes.  Here's a self-contained example of how to do that:

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FullScreenExample
{    
    static class GameFrame extends JFrame
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5386744421065461862L;
        private static final GraphicsDevice gd = (GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices())[0];
        private static final boolean FULLSCREEN_SUPPORTED = gd.isFullScreenSupported();
        private static final String MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT = "Make Full Screen";
        private static final String MAKE_WINDOWED_TEXT = "Make Windowed";
        private static final int WINDOWED_WIDTH = 400;
        private static final int WINDOWED_HEIGHT = 300;

        private final JButton fsButton = new JButton(MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT);
        private boolean isFullscreen = false;

        public GameFrame(String title)
        {
            super(title);
            setSize(WINDOWED_WIDTH, WINDOWED_HEIGHT);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            initComponents();
        }

        public void initComponents()
        {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            if(FULLSCREEN_SUPPORTED)
            {
                fsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {       
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        toggleFullscreen();
                    }
                });
                add(fsButton);
            }
            else
            {
                add(new JLabel("Fullscreen mode is not supported on this device"));
            }
        }

        public void toggleFullscreen()
        {
            isFullscreen = !isFullscreen;
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
            setUndecorated(isFullscreen);
            if(isFullscreen)
            {
                fsButton.setText(MAKE_WINDOWED_TEXT);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                validate();
            }
            else
            {
                fsButton.setText(MAKE_FULLSCREEN_TEXT);
                gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Game
    {
        private GameFrame gameFrame;

        public Game(String title)
        {
            gameFrame = new GameFrame(title);
        }

        public void start()
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    getGameFrame().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        public GameFrame getGameFrame()
        {
            return gameFrame;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game g = new Game("Foo");
        g.start();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I understand how to make the JFrame fullscreen. I need to know how to get the JFrame out of main, like how you might use getters and setters in other classes.

Comment: @user2653616: It's still very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. If you want to access your JFrame object outside of main(), you'll have to store it as a reference somewhere else - examples would include the class containing main(), your Game (as shown in the edited sample above), or some other object from which you can retrieve it. You can't just instantiate it in main(), not pass/store a reference to it, and expect to use it from some other scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, I phrased it wrong. I figured out I needed to declare the JFrame outside and reference it using game.frame inside main(). Thanks for trying!